# Not able to connect to redis on ec2 from another ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis

I am running redis 2.8.7 on one box. From other box (both are aws ec2) i am issuing  this command
redis-cli -h , but I get this error

Could not connect to Redis at :6379: Connection refused

port 6379 on box 1 is open for box2
Also, there is no id/pwd for redis

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

comment the  bind  line in redis.conf file
(make sure port 6379 is accessible only for specific machines)

More details at https://serverfault.com/questions/301788/how-do-you-get-redis-connections-working-within-an-amazon-vpc-private-subnet

Comment: I hv commented the bind, port is default 6379 and open, still I am not able to access from another ec2 machine. I tried private and public IP both to access. Even I tried telnet but no success. Please suggest what could be the possible reason

Answer (score 0):

Comment the bind line for local host and add the below bind line.

bind 0.0.0.0

and make sure you restart the redis-server for the changes to be effective.